# How can I run Prometheus on my local network for IoT?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, iot, esp8266

I recently set up a web server on an ESP8266 along with a DHT sensor for reporting temperature and humidity. I currently have this server outputting Prometheus metrics, but I'm wondering how I should set up a Prometheus instance on my local network.

I know one option is to just run it locally from my laptop - but are there any concerns with that such as what will happen if my laptop dies? I want to maximize uptime here. Should I run it inside of a container? If so, how?

Answer (score 2):

It is straightforward to run Prometheus in a container:

https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/installation/#using-docker

If you run Prometheus locally (container or not) then you're always going to have the risk of the machine on which it is running, dying; you break it, you own (fixing) it.

If you're willing to let someone else run Prometheus (and related) servers for you, are willing to let the metrics data be given to the third party (albeit securely), and are willing to take a latency hit (moving the data to/from the cloud), then you may want to explore managed Prometheus offerings such as Grafana Cloud:

https://go2.grafana.com/prometheus-grafana.html